# How to include multiple select boxes (drop down lists) in one search in PHP

Tags: php, select

I don't know how to implement different select boxes in one search. I need to make a search by name `ime[]`, second name `prezime[]` and years `godina rodjenja[]` at the same time. Every drop-down list has its name. I made search only by first drop-down list, but need to include all 3 boxes in one search.

The base with data is in a file called `v011db.php`. I need this only with php, not any other language.  This is my code:

HTML:

```
<fieldset>
        <form id="idpretraga" name="select_lista" action="v011.php" method="POST">
            <p>Pretraga:</p>
            Ime:
            <select name="ime[]">
                <option>Aleksa</option>
                <option>Bane</option>
                <option>Dejan</option>
                <option>Ivan</option>
                <option>Jovan</option>
                <option>Marko</option>
                <option>Milan</option>
                <option>Ljubisa</option>
                <option>Prazno - test</option>
            </select>

            Prezime
            <select name="prezime[]">
                <option>Ivanovic</option>
                <option>Ilic</option>
                <option>Markovic</option>
                <option>Ostojic</option>
                <option>Petrovic</option>
            </select>

            Godina rodjenja:
            <script>
                document.write("<select name='godina rodjenja[]'>");
                for (i = 1980; i <= new Date().getFullYear(); i++) {
                    document.write("<option>" + i + "</option>");
                }
                document.write("</select>");
            </script>

            <input type="submit" name="pretraga_dugme" value="Pretrazi">


        </form>
    </fieldset>
```

PHP:

```
    <?php
    require_once './v011db.php';

if (isset($_POST['pretraga_dugme'])) {
    foreach (($_POST['ime']) as $value) {
        $value;
    }

    $pretraga_imena = array_filter($bazaljudi, function($cbimena) {
        global $value;
        return $cbimena['ime'] == $value;
    }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);

    foreach ($pretraga_imena as $imena) {
        echo "<div>";
        foreach ($imena as $key => $value) {
            $key = ucfirst("$key");
            echo "<li>" . $key . ": <span style='color:red;'>" . $value . "</span></li>";
        }
        echo "</div>";
    }
    if (count($pretraga_imena)<1){
        echo '<div>Za trazeni pojam ne postoje rezultati</div>';
    }
}
    ?>
```

Comment: You're not actually _doing_ anything inside `foreach (($_POST['ime']) as $value) {`.  Are you intending to assign a value or something?

Comment: Also, please provide sample inputs (selected options) and show what the desired corresponding result/output is.

Comment: In $_POST['ime'] I tried to get $value, that I'll use in
$pretraga_imena = array_filter....  Results is an array that matches 'ime', 'prezime' and 'godina rodjena'. All 3 conditions must be fulfilled. in English ime=name, prezime=second name and 'godina rodjenja' = year of birth. So I search for all persons that have same name, second name and the year of birth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't mention in your question whether the different select boxes represent an AND condition or an OR condition. In other words, does an item need to match all conditions, or is it sufficient to match a single condition for it to be included in the results?

I'm assuming the variable `$bazaljudi` is defined inside of `v011db.php` and contains the list of things to filter. First, the following `foreach` loop seems a bit redundant to me:

```
foreach (($_POST['ime']) as $value) {
    $value;
}
```

After this loop runs, `$value` will still be defined and will contain the *last* entry contained in `$_POST['ime']`. All other values will basically be ignored. This may be what you intended, but running through a loop seems a bit of a strange way to get it. You could just as easily do something like `$value = end($_POST['ime'])` to get the same value without having to loop through the array.

Your actual search function then uses this value as a *global*, which is generally not good practice. This seems to be a pretty simple script, but if it was contained within a class or function or otherwise scoped, you could create a closure around that variable and not have to muddy up the global namespace:

```
$pretraga_imena = array_filter($bazaljudi, function($cbimena) use($value) {
    return $cbimena['ime'] == $value;
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
```

In any event, adding the ability for this function to return elements that match many different values is pretty straightforward. Here I'm introducing `$value2` and `$value3` as other values to filter against, which can be set from POST values:

```
$pretraga_imena = array_filter($bazaljudi, function($cbimena) use($value1, $value2, $value3) {
    return $cbimena['ime'] == $value1 ||
        $cbimena['another_key'] == $value2 ||
        $cbimena['even_more_keys'] == $value3
    ;
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
```

This will return items that match any of the conditions. Changing that so that it will return only items matching all conditions would be as simple as changing the `||` to `&&`. For extra brownie points, you could even choose whether it is an OR vs AND by a form control.

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation.
The search result should to match to all 3 conditions, so I used &&

This is the change I did to the code:
https://photos.app.goo.gl/wjjF333W1993c99k7
And this are errors :
https://photos.app.goo.gl/zdpQs6X2WLjv7xEt6

This si how v011db file looks like:
$bazaljudi = array(
    array(
        'ime' => 'Aleksa',
        'prezime' => 'Ivanovic',
        'godina rodjenja' => 1980
    ),
    
    array(
        'ime' => 'Aleksa',
        'prezime' => 'Petrovic',
        'godina rodjenja' => 1990
    ),
....
);

Comment: @AleksandarZivanovic I added the different `$value` variables, but left it up to you in order to set them from the `$_POST` values being sent in from the form. Setting those correctly should clear up that third error. I would try changing the form name `godina rodjenja[]` to `godina_rodjenja[]` and updating where you're inspecting that after the post, also.

Comment: One further observation, the form select elements are set up as arrays, but aren't `multiple` select. It may be you're looking at adding support for submitting multiple search terms for each key in the future, but defined that way is what is causing the POST to contain arrays rather than simple scalar values. Before you put the cart in front of the horse, it may be simpler to change them to scalar values (by removing the `[]`), in which case you shouldn't need to `foreach` or whatever, you can just grab the value directly out of `$_POST`.

Comment: You solved the problem. I changed 'godina rodjenja' to 'godina_rodjenja' and it works perfectly. Thank you for great explanations and tips.

Answer (score -2):

I dont know how is your query but for filter with multiple value you can do this:

```
$i = 0;
$selectedOptionCount = count($_POST['?']);
$selectedOption = "";
while ($i < $selectedOptionCount) {
    $selectedOption = $selectedOption . "'" . $_POST['?'][$i] . "'";
    if ($i < $selectedOptionCount - 1) {
        $selectedOption = $selectedOption . ", ";
    }

    $i ++;
}
$query = "SELECT ? WHERE ? in (" . $selectedOption . ")";
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't work with mysql database. I use a simple php file called v011db.php for all data. The file only contain multidimensional array that contain arrays with data (keys for subarrays are: "ime", "prezime" and "godina rodjenja").

Comment: you can explode array and insert like db you have tried?